# getting error as java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, json, web-services

I'm a fresher to Android(java) i'm just developing an simple apps that will call to webservice(Json Webservice) and bind the data to android:listview.
I created and JSON webservice and tested it was working flawlessly.In android when i give JSON WS URL and execute the program means it showing the error as

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.cargo.MainActivity$JSONParse.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:113)
```

in the line 113 which is

```
Cargo = json.getJSONArray(TAG_Track);
```

Dont know what was going wrong.I was stucking with this issues past 4 days.
here is my MainActivity code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
//import learn2crack.listview.library.JSONParser;

        public class MainActivity extends Activity {
            ListView listView1;
            TextView textView1;
            //TextView name;
            //TextView api;
            Button button1;
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> Track= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            //URL to get JSON Array
            private static String url = "http://192.168.1.126/testing/CService.asmx";

            //JSON Node Names 
            private static final String TAG_Track = "Track";
            private static final String TAG_Status = "Status";

            JSONArray Cargo = null;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                Track = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
                button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                         new JSONParse().execute();
                    }
                });
            }

            private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
                 private ProgressDialog pDialog;
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                  textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
                    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    pDialog.show();
                }
                @Override
                protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

                    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                    // Getting JSON from URL
                    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
                    return json;
                }
                 @Override
                 protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
                     pDialog.dismiss();
                     try {
                            // Getting JSON Array from URL

                            Cargo = json.getJSONArray(TAG_Track);
                            for(int i = 0; i < Cargo.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject c = Cargo.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                            String Status = c.getString(TAG_Status);
                            //String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // Adding value HashMap key => value

                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            map.put(TAG_Status, Status);
                            Track.add(map);
                            listView1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, Track,
                                    R.layout.listview,
                                    new String[] { TAG_Status }, new int[] {
                                            R.id.textView1});

                            listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
                            listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                        int position, long id) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at "+Track.get(+position).get("Status"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                            }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                 }
            }
        }
```

and here is my json parser code:

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public String getJSONString(HttpResponse response) {

        try {
             DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
           org.w3c.dom.Document doc = builder.parse(response.getEntity().getContent());
             NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("string");
             Node n = nl.item(0);
             String str = n.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
             System.out.println("Node value : " + str);
             return str;
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     return null;
    }
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
             while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                 sb.append(line);
             }
             is.close();

             json = sb.toString().substring(0, sb.toString().length()-1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            // JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(TEST_XML_STRING);
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

This is my logcat:

```
04-05 12:55:38.132: E/JSON Parser(768): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
04-05 12:55:38.172: E/AndroidRuntime(768): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 12:55:38.172: E/AndroidRuntime(768): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-05 12:55:38.172: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.example.cargo.MainActivity$JSONParse.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:113)
04-05 12:55:38.172: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.example.cargo.MainActivity$JSONParse.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
04-05 12:55:38.172: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:590)
04-05 12:55:38.172: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:149)
04-05 12:55:38.172: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:603)
04-05 12:55:38.172: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-05 12:55:38.172: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
04-05 12:55:38.172: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
04-05 12:55:38.172: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 12:55:38.172: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
04-05 12:55:38.172: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
04-05 12:55:38.172: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
04-05 12:55:38.172: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

can any once please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Move that part to doinbackground method, That is background task which is mainly try to access data from background.

Comment: at which line you are getting error.. mention that.

Comment: in line 113....updated my logcat

Comment: @InnocentKiller ...actually this is my first try in android so if you can , can you please make it breif?

Comment: @user3312615, whether below answer is working for you or not.

Comment: no..actually it displays extra "}" so once i remove that getting error "unhandeled exception type json exception "as near  Cargo = json.getJSONArray(TAG_Track);

Answer (score 0):

You are performing main operation in postExecute. PostExecute is used to display UI. Use that in doInBackground and display result UI in postExecute.

and what are all performed say jsonparsing display in doInBackground.

```
    void doInBackground()
                    {
                     try {
                            // Getting JSON Array from URL
                            //heavy operation like parsing do here..

                            Cargo = json.getJSONArray(TAG_Track);
                            for(int i = 0; i < Cargo.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject c = Cargo.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                            String Status = c.getString(TAG_Status);
                            //String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // Adding value HashMap key => value

                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            map.put(TAG_Status, Status);
                            Track.add(map);

}
                           void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
                            {
                            //just to display UI. use it in postExecute.
                             listView1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, Track,
                                    R.layout.listview,
                                    new String[] { TAG_Status }, new int[] {
                                            R.id.textView1});

                            listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
                            listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                        int position, long id) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at "+Track.get(+position).get("Status"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                            }
                            }
```

Comment: I changed the code as per your suggestion but nothing happens when button is clicked......I shows another error...How to reslove the below issue:   04-05 12:55:38.132: E/JSON Parser(768): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
            ListView listView1;
            TextView textView1;
            //TextView name;
            //TextView api;
            Button button1;
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> Track= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            //URL to get JSON Array
            private static String url = "http://192.168.1.126/testing/CService.asmx";

            //JSON Node Names 
            private static final String TAG_Track = "Track";
            private static final String TAG_Status = "Status";

            JSONArray Cargo = null;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                Track = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
                listView1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                         new JSONParse().execute();
                    }
                });

                listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                        int position, long id) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at "+Track.get(+position).get("Status"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
            }

            private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
                 private ProgressDialog pDialog;
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                  textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
                    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    pDialog.show();
                }
                @Override
                protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

                    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                    // Getting JSON from URL
                    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
                     Cargo = json.getJSONArray(TAG_Track);
                            for(int i = 0; i < Cargo.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject c = Cargo.getJSONObject(i);
                            }

                            // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                            String Status = c.getString(TAG_Status);
                            //String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // Adding value HashMap key => value

                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            map.put(TAG_Status, Status);
                            Track.add(map);

                    return json;
                }
                 @Override
                 protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
                     pDialog.dismiss();
                     try {
                            // Getting JSON Array from URL


                            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, Track,
                                    R.layout.listview,
                                    new String[] { TAG_Status }, new int[] {
                                            R.id.textView1});

                            listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
                            }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                 }
            }
        }
```